# How do I control the spacing between two tikzpictures?

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing

If I have two tikzpictures next to each other, how do I control the spacing between them?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,>=latex, font=\sffamily]
\draw[red] (-1.19,-1.19) rectangle (1.19,1.19);
\draw [->](-1,0) -- (1,0);
\node[right] at (0:0.95) {$\alpha$};
\draw [->](0,-1) -- (0,1);
\node[right] at (90:0.95) {$\beta$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,>=latex, font=\sffamily]
\draw[red] (-1.19,-1.19) rectangle (1.19,1.19);
\def\thetae{345}
\draw [->](-\thetae+180:1) -- (-\thetae:1);
\node[rotate=-\thetae, right] at (-\thetae:0.95) {$\alpha$};
\draw [->](-\thetae+270:1) -- (-\thetae+90:1);
\node[rotate=-\thetae, right] at (-\thetae+90:0.95) {$\beta$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like most latex constructs, a `tikzpicture` is a box so spacing is controlled as it would be between two letters. You have

```
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
```

which is like

```
hello
world
```

and puts one word space between them so they are side by side if they fit on the line.

You could have a blank line to put them in separate paragraphs one above the other, or

```
\end{tikzpicture}\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}
```

to force them out as far as possible, or any other space construct that you need.

Particularly in `standalone` you might want a fixed width so

```
\end{tikzpicture}\hspace{1cm}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: what if I want them to be flush against each other?

Comment: @JasonS just put them next to each other, latex doesn't insert any space   zzzz zzz stuff to force a linebreak in this comment: `\end{tikzpicture}\begin{tikzpicture}`

Comment: @JasonS Put a `%` after `\end{tikzpicture}` to hide the newline character from TeX.

Comment: If I do `\end{tikzpicture}\begin{tikzpicture}` there is still a small space between the rectangles, though

Comment: @JasonS isn't that white space within the picture, latex does not add any more

Comment: I guess it is, but I don't know where it comes from then.

Comment: @JasonS If I use `outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt` on the tikzpicture they touch (but it messes up the inner node spacing, not sure how to set it just for the outer box)